# Run inno setup from shared drive

Tags: inno-setup

I have created a inno setup installer for my application. Now I want to place that installer on a shared folder where the users can install from there.

The installer need to place the files on the `{%HOMEPATH}\{#MyAppName}`directory. But when I set the `AllowUNCPath=yes` it can be ran from the shared drive but it will install the files on the `fileshare\{%HOMEPATH}\{#MyAppName}`.

Is it possible to run the installer from the fileshare and install it on the user local drive?

My setup section looks like:

```
[Setup]    

    AppId="{{AAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAA}"
    AppName={#MyAppName}
    ;AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
    AppVersion={code:getVersionNumber}
    ;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
    AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
    DefaultDirName={%HOMEPATH}\{#MyAppName}
    DefaultGroupName={#MyAppPublisher}
    OutputDir=compiledInstaller
    OutputBaseFilename=setup
    SetupIconFile={#iconName}
    ;Set some installer settings
    Compression=lzma
    SolidCompression=yes
    ArchitecturesAllowed=x64
    PrivilegesRequired=lowest
    AllowCancelDuringInstall=False
    AllowUNCPath=false
    ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
    CreateUninstallRegKey=yes
    UsePreviousAppDir=yes
    ;Disable different screens
    DisableDirPage=yes
    DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
    DisableReadyPage=True
    DisableReadyMemo=True
    DisableFinishedPage=True
    DisableWelcomePage=True

    [Files]
    Source: "{#path}*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external recursesubdirs
    Source: "{#path}/.eclipseproduct"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external
    Source: "{#installerPath}/{#ScriptName}"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external
    Source: "{#installerPath}/{#iconName}"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external
```

The `path` and `installerPath` variables are linked to the files on the shared drive.

The error that I got when running the installer from the shared drive looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with a shared drive.

It's due to the `HOMEPATH` variable. Its value is like `\Users\username`. There's no drive in the path. So it can only ever work, if you run the installer from the `C:` drive. If you run it from anywhere else, the path is naturally resolved incorrectly.

You have to use an absolute path. You can use `USERPROFILE` variable instead of `HOMEPATH`. The `USERPROFILE` value is like `C:\Users\username`.